# Property not found on object of type error

Tags: objective-c, class-method

I am trying to access a class method from another class but I am getting error. I have a class 'Constants' in which I have written a class method 'changeDateFormat' and accessing it from some viewController.
Here is my code.

Constants.h

```
@interface Constants : NSObject

+(NSString *)changeDateFormat:(NSString *)currentDate;

@end
```

Constans.m

```
@implementation Constants

+(NSString *)changeDateFormat: (NSString *) currentDate
{
    NSString *convertedDate = @"";
    @try
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDate];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];

        convertedDate = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date];
    }
    @catch(NSException *e)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", e.name, e.reason);
    }
    return convertedDate;
}

@end
```

I am trying to access the above method like `Constants.changeDateFormat:@"Mar 11 2018"` but I am getting error - Property not found on object of type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the `changeDateFormat:` method. You don't use a `.` for that. This is the correct syntax:

```
NSString *output = [Constants changeDateFormat:input];
```